# Listen to Changes on 2 Dependent Fields in Angular 9 Reactive forms

Tags: angular, angular8, angular-reactive-forms, angular9

I have 2 form fields in angular reactive forms, where when I change the % gain, the price changes immediately, and when the price is changed, the % is computed and changes immediately.

I did the following:

```
const avgPrice = this.totalStockProductForm.get('AVERAGE_PRICE').value;
this.totalStockProductForm.get('PERCENTAGE_GAIN').valueChanges.subscribe(percentage => {
    this.totalStockProductForm.controls['FINAL_PRODUCT_PRICE'].patchValue(
        avgPrice + avgPrice * (percentage / 100)
    );
});
this.totalStockProductForm.get('FINAL_PRODUCT_PRICE').statusChanges.subscribe(finalPrice => {
    this.totalStockProductForm.controls['PERCENTAGE_GAIN'].patchValue(
        ((finalPrice - avgPrice) / avgPrice) * 100
    );
});
```

I know, and it eventually happened, this will lead to infinite loop. How can I achieve my goal of changing one entry and previewing change immediately on the other?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
const avgPrice = this.totalStockProductForm.get('AVERAGE_PRICE').value;
this.totalStockProductForm.get('PERCENTAGE_GAIN').valueChanges.subscribe(percentage => {
    this.totalStockProductForm.controls['FINAL_PRODUCT_PRICE'].patchValue(
        avgPrice + avgPrice * (percentage / 100),
        { emitEvent: false }
    );
});
this.totalStockProductForm.get('FINAL_PRODUCT_PRICE').statusChanges.subscribe(finalPrice => {
    this.totalStockProductForm.controls['PERCENTAGE_GAIN'].patchValue(
        ((finalPrice - avgPrice) / avgPrice) * 100,
        { emitEvent: false }
    );
});
```

adding { emitEvent: false } will block detecton of other events on the other fields which resolves the infinite loop issue! Hope it helps someone!

Comment: But `emitEvent` relates to a form control. What if I have ngModel instead?

Answer (score 1):

I managed to fix it now, changed `patchValue` to `setValue` which did the job :)